# How to convert a pandas Series with multiple object into string series?

Tags: python, string, pandas, types, series

I would like to convert my series into strings :

```
s = pd.Series({'A':[10,'héllo','world']})
```

to something like this

```
s = pd.Series({'A':['10','héllo','world']})
```

But whithout using iteration. I tried to used pandas.DataFrame.astype but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you've defined a **series of lists**:

```
s = pd.Series({'A':[10,'héllo','world']})

print(s)

A    [10, héllo, world]
dtype: object
```

If this is truly what you have, you need to modify each list in a Python-level loop. For example, via `pd.Series.apply`:

```
s = s.apply(lambda x: list(map(str, x)))
```

If you have a **series of scalars**, then `astype` will work:

```
s = pd.Series([10,'héllo','world'])

res = s.astype(str)

print(res, res.map(type), sep='\n'*2)

0       10
1    héllo
2    world
dtype: object

0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was not a series, but a dataframe column.
And apply is using iteration rigth ?

Comment: Yes, `apply` uses iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
string_series = s.apply(lambda val: str(val))
```

but that is iterating in the background.

You should note that

```
s.astype(str)
```

does not operate in place but returns a copy.

Comment: This won't match OP's desired output, it gives `"[10, 'héllo', 'world']"` if you run `s.apply(lambda val: str(val)).iat[0]`.